# Existence of transversals of subgroups implies axiom of choice?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, axiom-of-choice

If $G$ is a group and $H\leq G$ is a subgroup, then a transversal of $H$ is a subset $T\subseteq G$ which meets every coset of $H$ in a unique point.

The axiom of choice clearly implies that every subgroup of a group has a transversal. But does the converse hold? I'm sure somebody must have proved this, but I haven't been able to find a reference.

Comment: Actually, even with AC, the existence of a set meeting every coset of $H$ in a unique point is only guaranteed in special cases, e.g. if $H$ is finite, or if $H$ has finite index in $G$, or of course if $H$ is a normal subgroup. In general, all that is guaranteed by AC is the existence of a set meeting every left coset (or every right coset) in a unique point.

Answer (score 2):

> Keremedis, K. "**[Some equivalents of AC in algebra. II](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s000120050073)**". *Algebra Universalis* **39** (1998), no. 3-4, 163–169.

The first theorem proves that requiring this just for Abelian groups is enough to prove the axiom of choice.